# line is erasing in java

Tags: java, graphics

I make an Application in java and draw rectangle. When I search from combobox the rectangle is under the combobox and when I close combobox some parts of the rectangle which was under the combobox is deleted. How can I make rectangle to be visible after the combobox was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you read [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html). As suggested there, call the super.paint(g) *after* your own painting.

Answer (score 0):

repaint the panel in which the rectangle is visible